# How to wait AppDelegate is finish before ViewController start?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, appdelegate, onesignal

I have an issue happening after first launch of my application only.

I'm sure this is because my ViewController is loading faster than AppDelegate then OneSignal userId variable isn't yet set so my webview link load without userId value and doesn't show the dynamic content it's supposed to...

In my AppDelegate.swift I have some regular OneSignal settings and at the end line 76 :

```
let userId = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().subscriptionStatus.userId
```

That line will collect unique userId from smartphone.

In my ViewController.swift I have this :

```
@IBOutlet var webview: WKWebView!

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

private var monNom: String = ""

let playerId64 = (toBase64(word: userId ?? ""))

@IBOutlet weak var compteApplication: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.example.com/index.php?application::::::::::::::\(playerId64)")!))
    
    
    
}
```

I'm new to Swift and I would like you to teach me how to solve this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Main.storyboard` reference from `info.plist`. There would be two places to remove from, you'll see them when you expand all the values. Now you can load the `ViewController` in `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate` manually by setting the `rootViewController` property of the `window`.

Comment: Sorry i'm a bit lost with your answer my skills are very limited. Do you think there could be an alternative as a line of code to write inside the ViewController.swift that could simply wait userId has value before continuing and load webview ?

Comment: Why not just load the userId in `viewDidLoad` instead of `AppDelegate`.

Comment: If I move the line that get the userId to viewDidLoad it write in red "Use of unresolved identifier 'OneSignal'. I tryed a sleep 4 secondes but looks like it put into sleep the whole application instead of just ViewController. I was thinking something like if userId is not set then put into sleep viewcontroller 1 seconde

Comment: "Use of unresolved identifier 'OneSignal'- You will have to import `OneSignal` in your view controller or whichever framework you have imported in AppDelegate.

Comment: @Jithin Ok I imported OneSignal then no more red message and I've put the let userId = OneSignal... inside the override func viewDidLoad as suggested by Frankenstein it did not solve the problem. userId not set and I have to task kill the App then reopen it for the webview loads with userId in URL